# How to Convert Complex Type in to java.lang.string during class generation from schema(.xsd) using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an schema where a complex element 'LOBCd' is defined of Complex Type 'PC_LINE_OF_BUSINESS'.

Schema :

```
<xsd:element name="LOBCd" type="PC_LINE_OF_BUSINESS"/>
<xsd:complexType name="PC_LINE_OF_BUSINESS">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now I want this LOB_Cd in form of string in java model class after model generation using JAXB. But currently there is a java file 'PCLINEOFBUSINESS' is getting generated and 'ClaimsPartyInfo' where lobCd type is 'PCLINEOFBUSINESS'.

I required 'lobCd' in java.lang.String in the generated 'ClaimsPartyInfo' file.

Java:

```
public class ClaimsPartyInfo {
@XmlElement(name = "LOBCd", required = true)
protected PCLINEOFBUSINESS lobCd;
```

Please help.

Comment: edit the quesiont to place the comment inside and add all info you need

Answer (score 0):

Your "`PC_LINE_OF_BUSINESS`" is of complex type so **JAXB** will create a class for it and whatever your root node for this that, this Class "`PC_LINE_OF_BUSINESS`" will be referenced there.

You can try modifying your **XSD** if you are designing it.

Or otherwise you have to modify the Classes manually after identifying it.

Comment: Hi Kulbhushan ,Thx for the reply :

Comment: Actually the problem is ,  schema file is provided by client so i can,t modify that and the file is very big in size (contains thousands of accord object of Complex Type) and modified by client regularly, so manually changing the java file would be very difficult   :-(

Comment: Oh ok.... But i cannot see any way to in which you can make simple attributes of class. What is your purpose of doing that we can see some other way around.

Comment: Purpose of this is to support some request processing based on XML request format.
basically Client has one processing engine which processes the xml request

Something like :

<PersPolicy>
 <PolicyNumber>2170</PolicyNumber>           <CompanyProductCd>APV</CompanyProductCd>
<LOBCd>APV</LOBCd>

Here LOBCd is getting processed as form of 'String' but its actual type is defined in schema is 'PC_LINE_OF_BUSINESS' which actually represent any String value

Comment: They also defined the extension base type as 'string' for all complex type in schema.
<xsd:complexType name="PC_LINE_OF_BUSINESS">
  <xsd:simpleContent>
   <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">

Comment: so when we process the XML request (after creating java objects from the schema) we require to pass these objects in the request process engine where the actual value should be of type 'string'

Comment: Anything if you have suggestion on : like if any schema 'Complex type' has extension base as 'xsd:string'  then using jaxb generation these complex type can be generated as 'String' in java classes.